# Unknown bottom blob 'data' (layer 'conv1', bottom index 0)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

Trying to train LeNet on my own dataset. I generated HDF5 file from my long 1D vectordata set and created HDF5 data layer as follows: I named the top blobs same as I did when I generate my HDF5.

```
name: "Test_net"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "Inputdata"
  top: "label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source:"~/*_hdf5_train.txt"
    batch_size: 32
  }
  include{phase: TRAIN}
}
layer {
  name: "data2"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "Inputdata"
  top: "label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source:"~/*_hdf5_test.txt"
    batch_size: 32
  }
  include{phase: TEST}
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {lr_mult:1}
  param {lr_mult:2}
  convolution_param{
    num_output: 20
    kernel_h: 1
    kernel_w: 5
    stride_h: 1
    stride_w: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"     
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param{
    pool: MAX
    kernel_h: 1
    kernel_w: 2
    stride_h: 1
    stride_w: 2
  }
}
# more layers here...
layer{
  name: "loss"
  type: "SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss"
  bottom: "ip2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

But then when I tried to train I am having the following error from `insert_split.cpp`.

> ```
> insert_splits.cpp:29] Unknown bottom blob 'data' (layer 'conv1',   bottom     index 0)
>   *** Check failure stack trace: ***
>   @     0x7f19d7e735cd  google::LogMessage::Fail()
>   @     0x7f19d7e75433  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
>   @     0x7f19d7e7315b  google::LogMessage::Flush()
>   @     0x7f19d7e75e1e  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
>   @     0x7f19d82684dc  caffe::InsertSplits()
>   @     0x7f19d8230d5e  caffe::Net<>::Init()
>   @     0x7f19d8233f21  caffe::Net<>::Net()
>   @     0x7f19d829c68a  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
>   @     0x7f19d829d9f7  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
>   @     0x7f19d829dd9a  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
>   @     0x7f19d8211683  caffe::Creator_SGDSolver<>()
>   @           0x40a6c9  train()
>   @           0x4071c0  main
>   @     0x7f19d6dc8830  __libc_start_main
>   @           0x4079e9  _start
>   @              (nil)  (unknown)
>  Aborted (core dumped)
> ```

What did I do wrong?

Cheers,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caffe Unknown bottom blob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38730972/caffe-unknown-bottom-blob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data layer outputs two "blobs": `"label"` and **`"Inputdata"`**. Your `"conv1"` layer expects as input a "blob" named **`"data"`**. Caffe does not know that you meant `"Inputdata"` and `"data"` to be the same blob...
Now, since you already saved the hdf5 files with `"Inputdata"` name, you cannot change this name in the `"HDF5Data"` layer, what you can do is change `"data"` to `"Inputdata"` in the "bottom" of `"conv1"` layer.

---

PS,
Your loss layer requires two "bottom"s: `ip2` and `label` you forgot to feed.

Comment: Appreciate your help, Shai. I actually was trying to do training without testing, just to see if my network starts training. For that I had #test_iter and #test_interval commented. Now I tried both training with and without testing(copy of training set as testing set, it shouldn't matter I guess) and I am having the same issue. I also added label to my loss layer, please see the edited prototxt.

Comment: That worked thanks. Now I am having ....hdf5_data_layer.cpp:88] Failed to open source file: ~/*_hdf5_train.txt error.

Comment: @user2413711 you cannot have wildcard (`"*"`) in the `path` of the hdf5 list file. you should have a **single** text file that lists all the paths to the binary hdf5 files you are using as train/test.

Comment: Yeah, that is just not to post my actual path here, I have an absolute path like source: "/A/B/C/D/test_hdf5_train.txt"

Comment: @user2413711 make sure your path is correct. the error message is quite clear: caffe cannot open "/A/B/C/D/test_hdf5_train.txt". make sure the file is indeed there and that you grant read permission to the file.

Comment: I am having this error now....layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer conv1
F1006 04:26:07.040401 11022 layer_factory.hpp:81] Check failed: registry.count(type) == 1 (0 vs. 1) Unknown layer type: convolution (known types: AbsVal, Accuracy, ArgMax, BNLL, BatchNorm, BatchReindex, Bias, Concat, ContrastiveLoss, Convolution, Crop, Data, Deconvolution, Dropout, DummyData, ELU, Eltwise, Embed, EuclideanLoss, Exp, Filter, Flatten, HDF5Data, HDF5Output, HingeLoss, Im2col, ImageData, InfogainLoss, InnerProduct, Input, LRN, LSTM, LSTMUnit, Log, MVN, MemoryData, MultinomialLogisticLoss, PReLU...

Comment: @user2413711 it's `"Convolution"` with capital "C"

Comment: This one followed up: Check failed: num_spatial_axes_ == 2 (0 vs. 2) kernel_h & kernel_w can only be used for 2D convolution.

Comment: @user2413711 what is the shape of `Inputdata`?

Comment: 100x3000 and label 1x100, this is just for a test. My actual data will be  very large Nx3000

Comment: @user2413711 please ask a new question. it's too broad for a comment